# Measuring peak memory usage of Perl process with Valgrind

Tags: perl, memory, profiling, valgrind

I'm trying to determine the peak (heap) memory usage of a Perl script using Valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --depth=1 /usr/bin/perl script.pl arguments
```

Valgrind seems to start up just fine, the script executes, but no `massif.out.PID` file is generated. I've successfully used the same kind of command with C and Lua programs but for some reason it doesn't seem to work with this Perl script.

*I'm on Mac OS 10.6.6, my Perl is the system standard `v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level` and my Valgrind is 3.6.1 (from MacPorts).*

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work just fine on Ubuntu 9.04, same Perl version, and Valgrind v3.4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the trace-children option. This one works fine for me

```
valgrind --tool=massif --depth=1 --trace-children=yes perl script.pl
```